# timing of JSON AJAX Response in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, facebook-graph-api

I think this is more down to timing than code, so really I am looking for best practice advice on how best to get a JSON response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#messages').append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loading" />');

                var ideaid = <?php echo $_GET['ideaid']; ?>;
                $.ajax({

                    url: 'sql/ajaxsql.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'switch=commentList&ideaid=' + ideaid + '&filter=sortdate',
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(result) {
                        var len = result.length;
                        var html;
                        console.log('length= ' + len);
                        $('#response').remove();
                        console.log(result);
                        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            var pic = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + result[i].user_id + '/picture&type=small" align="middle" />';
                            var authname;
                            FB.api('/' + result[i].user_id + '?fields=name', function(AuthName) {
                                console.log(AuthName);
                                alert(AuthName.name);
                               authname = AuthName.name;

                            });
                            html = '<p>' + result[i].comment + '<br><hr>Date Added: ' + result[i].date + ' by ' + pic + ' ' + authname + '<br><hr><hr></p>';
                            $('#comms').append(html);

                        }

                        $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
                            $(this).remove();

                        });
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });

        </script>
```

With this code, it fires off to get comments regarding a certain idea (idea_id).  The comments only holds the Users ID (facebook).  When all the data is back, the success then sorts the data ready to print to the screen in some order.

As part of the success, I have the date, time, FB image and name as part of the Author Info under each comment.

Date and Time, works. Image using the graph works, but the name is a bit late of the window loading, and so misses it's call, so comes back as undefined and then the Alert pops up with the name.  I understand ajax is meant to do this.

Whats the best way to get round this.

Thank you in advance.

Andrew

**EDIT**

I have been unable to make this work, even with the suggestions below.

***EDIT AGAIN** Just seen bf new updated version as below. would also have worked. But I have spent a day on this one function and dare not to play.*

As soon as the FB.api comes into play, I could not get the values from out side it.  So I took a different approach.

Rather than ajax, I used the query from the PHP side that gets the data, including the uid and then json queried that, and bolted it onto the (mysql_fetch_array) array as follows:

```
         $gc_result = mysql_query($gc_query);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($gc_result)) {
        $jsonURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $result['user_id'] . "/";
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonURL), true);
        $result["name"] = $json['name'];

        $data[] = $result;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Now I have that, I can then do the following and call it within the jQuery:

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var pic = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + result[i].user_id + '/picture?type=small" align="middle" />';
     html = '<p>' + result[i].comment + '<br><hr>Date Added: ' + result[i].date + ' by ' + pic + ' ' + **result[i]['name']** + '<br><hr><hr></p>';
     $('#comms').append(html);  
                        }
```

This all works great, and I am a complete novice to programming jquery and using Facebook API and JSON, but even I sit back and am pretty impressed with this solution.   Before I get carried away, are there any potential flaws in this, performance or security wise ???

Thanks again in Advance.

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `FB.api` is probably asynchronous (another ajax request), so you have to move the code after it to inside the `FB.api` callback:

```
FB.api('/' + result[i].user_id + '?fields=name', function(AuthName) {
    console.log(AuthName);
    alert(AuthName.name);
    authname = AuthName.name;
    html = '<p>' + result[i].comment + '<br><hr>Date Added: ' + result[i].date + ' by ' + pic + ' ' + authname + '<br><hr><hr></p>';
    $('#comms').append(html);
});
```

---

You also have a variable scope problem because of the `for` loop. One of the ways to fix this is to use a separate function to create the callback. Add this right after your `$(window).load` block, before `</script>`:

```
function createFbApiCallback(jsonResult) {
    return function(AuthName) {
        var authname = AuthName.name;
        var pic = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + jsonResult.user_id + '/picture&type=small" align="middle" />';
        var html = '<p>' + jsonResult.comment + '<br><hr>Date Added: ' + jsonResult.date + ' by ' + pic + ' ' + authname + '<br><hr><hr></p>';
        $('#comms').append(html);
    }
}
```

Then change your loop to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    FB.api('/' + result[i].user_id + '?fields=name', createFbApiCallback(result[i])); 
}
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used FB.api, but I recall that being the case. I'm 95% sure it is async

Comment: By moving the end tag for the FB.api, I am getting an undefined error on the result[i] ??

Comment: Strange, it should be accessible. Try defining an alias for just before calling `FB.api`: `var currentResult = result[i]`, then use that inside the callback.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
var pic = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + result[i].user_id + '/picture&type=small" align="middle" />';
var authname;
var currentResult = result[i];
FB.api('/' + result[i].user_id + '?fields=name', function(AuthName) {
console.log(currentResult);
alert(currentResult.name);
authname = AuthName.name;
html = '<p>' + currentResult[i].comment + '<br><hr>Date Added: ' + currentResult[i].date + ' by ' + pic + ' ' + authname + '<br><hr><hr></p>';
$('#comms').append(html);
});
}`
Now getting the var authname printed, but the date/time and comment are undefined?

Comment: It feels like when the API is called, its only taking currentResult.user_id into it, rather than the whole array.

Comment: You have a scope problem because of the loop. See the update above.

Comment: Sorry bfavaretto, I did not see your reply in time.  I have marked your answer correct, because I can see the logic, but I came up with another way of doing it.  If you can see above under EDIT.  Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Your solution will perform much better than that bunch of ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to execute code that relies on a callback function inside another callback function, execute your code inside the most inner callback function. In your case, move all that is out of the FB API callback to be inside it, so all your DOM manipulation is done only when both the AJAX response and the FB.api response has returned.

Comment: It cannot all go inbetween because it relies on the for statement to get the correct row.  I understand the logic, but once the api is called, it's asking for a uid which is not yet given as an element ?

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
FB.api('/' + result[i].user_id + '?fields=name', function(AuthName) {
var pic = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + 
result[i].user_id + '/picture&type=small" align="middle" />';
var authname;
console.log(AuthName);
authname = AuthName.name;
html = '<p>' + result[i].comment + '<br><hr>Date Added: ' + result[i].date + ' by ' + pic + ' ' + authname + '<br><hr><hr></p>';
$('#comms').append(html);
});
}`

This gives me a pic that's undefined error as an example?